# What's wrong with this regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to match Twitter-Hashtags within an Android-App, but my code doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to.
What I came up with is:

```
ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>(0);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b#[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet); // tweet contains the tweet as a String
while(m.find()){
    tags.add(m.group());
}
```

The variable tweet contains a regular tweet including hashtags - but find() doesn't trigger. So I guess my regular expression is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex fails because of the `\b` word boundary anchor. This anchor only matches between a non-word character and a word-character (alphanumeric character). So putting it directly in front of the `#` causes the regex to fail unless there is an alphanumeric character *before* the `#`! Your regex would match a hashtag in `foobarfoo#hashtag blahblahblah` but not in `foobarfoo #hashtag blahblahblah`.

Use `#\w+` instead, and remember, inside a string, you need to double the backslashes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\\w+");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern should be "#(\\w+)" if you are trying to just match the hash tag.  Using this and the tweet "retweet pizza to #pizzahut", doing m.group() would give "#pizzahut" and m.group(1) would give "pizzahut".

Edit: Note, the html display is messing with the backslashes for escape, you'll need to have two for the w in your string literal in Java.